# Listview Spinner Android:

Tags: android, android-listview, android-spinner

I have an strange issue. I design listview with spinner. Spinner enable only in heading row. It's working in  Samsung galaxy tab2, And lenovo tablets. Now one of the friend complaint it's not working in his `Samsung Galaxy Tab 3 10.1 P5220` tablet?. Is it any possible to happen like this?. I didn't see his tablet.

Comment: You have a weird design... why not simply a spinner **outside** the ListView (header / footer) to act as a filter? Wouldn't it be a cleaner design?

Comment: My each spinner contains different item.
I have Two items heading, subitem. Only heading row contains the spinner. Which is not for filtering the items.

Comment: And... do you really need Spinners in your rows? Can't it be simplified to TextViews?

Comment: Then how to get popup with list of items

Comment: So... each row must contain a choice? Sounds creepy.

Comment: no heading row contains that spinner. Already i mention it is not choice. I need to store different data for each heading.